# Dialog class where the message can be modified dynamically

Tags: android

I am looking for a Dialog class where the message that is set to an instance of the class (e.g., via setMessage) can be changed depending on the situation. Is this possible? Or are messages that are set permanent (thereby requiring a new instance of the Dialog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean `AlertDialog`, because as @Sam says, `Dialog` has no `setMessage()` method. Of course, you can use the same `AlertDialog` instance. Just `setMessage()` and show. Just keep in mind you will lose previous message.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), the generic [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) doesn't have a `setMessage()` method. You can use `findViewById()` to find the TextView you passed to `setContentView()` and call `setText()` on that. Or just use an AlertDialog if appropriate.